# Building javascript "packages" from source files

Tags: javascript

I want to develop JavaScript as I would Java, in the form of packages.

I have the following files:

```
/src/package/ClassA.js
/src/package/subpackage/ClassB.js
```

ClassA.js:

```
function ClassA ()
{
    this.myB = new package.subpackage.ClassB("hello");
}
```

ClassB.js:

```
function ClassB (myStr)
{
    this.b = myStr;
}
```

Is there anything that will build this for me into:

```
package.js
```

which would look something like:

```
var package =
    {
        ClassA:
        function ()
        {
            this.myB = new package.subpackage.ClassB("hello");
        },

        subpackage:
        {
            ClassB:
            function (myStr)
            {
                this.b = myStr;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which would allow me to do something like:

```
var t = new package.ClassA();

console.log(t);
```

Comment: you can concat the files and add something at the end like this: package={ClassA:ClassA, subpackage: {ClassB: ClassB}};

Comment: What if there are multiple ClassB's but in different packages.

Comment: then the most recent one wins! OR, you can concat an anon function opener before the two files, and a exporting footer after the two files. in my given example, prepend "(function(){", and append ";self.package=package;}());" to the concat'd body. choppy but amazingly effective...

Comment: @dandavis was hoping for a tool that would do it all for me!

Comment: a tool would be nice, but i haven't seen anything like that, and judging from the response thus far, there may not be one. if we don't hear anything, i'll build something myself...